# Transformar Imagem em byte?

Tags: c#

Eu preciso capturar uma imagem de uma folder no /doc, escrever seus **bytes** em um arquivo de texto e salvar em outra pasta no /doc.

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: O correto é escrever os _bytes_ num arquivo de texto. Uma imagem (assim como qualquer arquivo) **é um conjunto de bytes**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode tentar o seguinte:

```
// Carrega sua imagem e salva em um array de bytes
byte[] imgdata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Test\simba.jpg");

// Salva seu array de bytes em um arquivo
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Test\byteArray.txt", imgdata);
```

Se a pasta se encontra no *My Documents* (Meus Documentos), você pode usar o seguinte código para buscar sua imagem:

```
string pathToImage = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "nomeDaSuaImagem.jpg");
```

Note que eu usei uma imagem `.jpg`. Se a sua imagem for em outro formato, altere para o formato desejado, como por exemplo `.png`, `.bmp`, `.gif`, etc.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Resolveu meu problema.

Comment: @ViniciusMarson Lembrando que se a resposta lhe ajudou, marque-a como correta para ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema!